Memory leak in CoreML variable Image size
I have converted fast-neural-style PyTorch model into Core ML. It works fine when I set a fixed-size input image when converting it into CoreML model. However, when I set a variable-size image and convert it into a Core ML model, the VNImageRequest uses too much memory.
    func makeArt(_ image: UIImage) {
    do {
        let modelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration()
        // Load yoru model
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: StarryNight(configuration: modelConfiguration).model)
        
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, error in
            if let results = request.results as? [VNPixelBufferObservation],
               let pixelBuffer = results.first?.pixelBuffer {
                
                // Convert the pixel buffer to CIImage
                let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
                let context = CIContext()
                
                // Create CGImage
                if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
                    // Convert CGImage to UIImage
                    self.output = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                    // Use the processed UIImage (uiImage)
                }
            } else {
                print("No results or invalid format")
            }
        }
        
     
        if  let cgImage = image.cgImage {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
            try handler.perform([request])
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

Here is the converter code:
coreml_model = ct.convert(
traced_model,
inputs=[
    ct.ImageType(
        name="input",
        shape=(1, 3, ct.RangeDim(128, 1024), ct.RangeDim(128, 1024)) ,   
        scale=1/255.0   
    )
],
outputs=[ct.ImageType(name="output",  scale=1, bias=[0, 0, 0])])

Is there any solution to this?
